# Split identifier string python

Tags: python, string, split

```
DB00002
DB00914
DB00222
DB01056
```

I have a list of database ID and want to trim it down to contain number only e.g. (2,914,222,1056) How can I do this in python? Many thanks!

Comment: And all your strings start with `DB`?

Answer (score 1):

Just exclude the first two characters and convert the rest to `int`.

```
data = ["DB00002", "DB00914", "DB00222", "DB01056"]
print [int(item[2:]) for item in data ]
# [2, 914, 222, 1056]
```

If you are not sure about the number of characters which are not numbers, you can skip them using generator expression, like this

```
[int("".join(char for char in item if char.isdigit())) for item in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you want to remove the frist two chars and convert the rest into integer:

```
text = "DB00914"
num = int(text[2:])
```